# C/C++ shared memory with Erlang

Tags: c, erlang

How can I pass an array between Erlang and an external C/C++ programs, assuming that the array is created and initialized by the Erlang program? ( I do not want to copy the whole array)?

P.S: I need a shared memory environment between C/C++ and Erlang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "array" you mean something that your C/C++ can easily access as an array, then you'll want to use an Erlang binary. These are easily handled in C/C++ code written as a [NIF](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html) or [driver](http://www.erlang.org/doc/tutorial/c_portdriver.html). For example, given an Erlang function that takes a binary as an argument, you could implement it in C as a NIF as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "erl_nif.h"

static ERL_NIF_TERM
binfunc(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    ErlNifBinary bin;
    unsigned i;

    if (argc != 1 || !enif_inspect_binary(env, argv[0], &bin))
        return enif_make_badarg(env);
    printf("received binary of length %zu\r\ndata: ", bin.size);
    for (i = 0; i < bin.size; ++i)
        printf("%x ", bin.data[i]);
    printf("\r\n");
    return enif_make_atom(env, "ok");
}

static ErlNifFunc nif_funcs[] =
{
    {"binfunc", 1, binfunc}
};

ERL_NIF_INIT(nif,nif_funcs,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

The Erlang function would be implemented like this:

```
-module(nif).
-export([binfunc/1]).
-on_load(init/0).

init() ->
    erlang:load_nif("./nif", 0).

binfunc(_Bin) ->
    {error, "nif not loaded"}.
```

Running it would look like this:

```
Erlang/OTP 17 [RELEASE CANDIDATE 2] [erts-6.0] [source-f91fbb2] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.0  (abort with ^G)
1> nif:binfunc(<<"abcdef">>).
received binary of length 6
data: 61 62 63 64 65 66
ok
```

This implements just a simple array of chars, but using [Erlang's powerful bit syntax](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.6/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) you can easily implement structs, arrays, etc. that you can exchange between Erlang and C/C++.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Steve, but this only works for a simple C program. I cannot employ this for a large project. I wonder if there is an efficient way of sharing large data between 2 completely independent applications.

Comment: Actually, this technique works for large-scale applications that go well beyond being "simple C programs." But putting that aside, have you instead considered using an in-memory database shared between your applications?

Comment: Well @Steve, I think that would make the things more complicated. Let me try this once again. I will let you know. Thanks!